# Concurrent ModificationException in Listview data

Tags: java, android, listview

I am sorting my list data after every modification but since several threads could call the sorting method block, I decided to put it in a `synchronized` block. My code is as shown below. Problem is, despute the `synchronized` block, I am still getting 'ConcurrentModificationExceptio' on the line `Collections.sort(storageBckupData.get(msg.what).getTotalItems(),new BackupDataComparator());`. Any reason why I keep getting this?

```
 class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                default:
                    synchronized(LOCK) {
                        while(inUse) {
                            try {
                                LOCK.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        inUse = true;

                        Collections.sort(storageBckupData.get(msg.what).getTotalItems(),new BackupDataComparator());

                        inUse = false;
                        LOCK.notifyAll();
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is not about whether you have synchronized or not, its when the collection detects a modification being done concurrently with something that does not allow it. For example you might have (somewhere else in your code which you are not showing) an iterator going through the list of items. Its about protecting the integrity of the collection.

What is happening in the other thread? Is it going through the list in parallel? 
Draw a [Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) of both threads and you should clearly find what one thread is doing in parallel of the other.

Also, do you actually need to do that locking? You can get a synchronized collection through methods such as [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Why don't you use an appropriate data structure that takes care of sorting more efficiently? If each item is unique you could use a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) implementation such as [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. Why dint I think of `TreeSet` and `Collections.synchronizedList()`; Thanks a lot.